# Simple solution to execute remote windows commands for linux python

Tags: python, linux, windows, remote-access

I'm looking for a way to run windows applications through a python script that is run on a remote Linux machine. 
Linux machine a server that can trigger python scripts on it's side. I need that python script to be able to execute commands (while passing arguments) on a Windows 7 machine. The thing I'd like to have is simplicity on the cost of safety. Both machines work in a closed environment, ethernet connected.
I suppose the best way to achieve it is to have some sort of execution server running on my Windows desktop that could be triggered remotely.

Perhaps you have some suggestions ?

Comment: ssh doesn't exist on wnidows unless you install something like mingw/cygwin.

Comment: ok, ssh was not a best example at all, I need something like an execution server working on my desktop machine - I'll edit my post

Answer (score 0):

I need to connect from a Windows machine to a remote Linux server and execute a Perl script. I've tried using

```html
command = "perl /usr/local/xfer/file.pl -ssh root@"+hostname+" -pw password -batch"
pid = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

The command above uses the Perl installation on Windows but you said the script is located on a Linux server.

So you need to wrap the invocation in a call to ssh:

```html
child = subprocess.Popen(['plink', '-ssh', 'user@server', 'perl', '/usr/local/xfer/file.pl', '-ssh', 'root@'+hostname, '-pw', 'password', '-batch'], shell=True)
```